# Module installs but cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to run a Python2 script on a Mac that depends on a module, which I have installed but according to the script can't be found. Why is the following failing?

```
Home:Dev m$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
Home:Dev m$ sudo pip install coincurve==5.2.0 pysha3
Password:
The directory '/Users/m/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/m/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting coincurve==5.2.0
  Downloading coincurve-5.2.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (157kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting pysha3
  Downloading pysha3-1.0.2.tar.gz (829kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 829kB 692kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from coincurve==5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from coincurve==5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.3.0->coincurve==5.2.0)
Installing collected packages: coincurve, pysha3
  Running setup.py install for pysha3 ... done
Successfully installed coincurve-5.2.0 pysha3-1.0.2
Home:Dev m$ pip show coincurve
Name: coincurve
Version: 5.2.0
Summary: Cross-platform Python CFFI bindings for libsecp256k1
Home-page: https://github.com/ofek/coincurve
Author: Ofek Lev
Author-email: ofekmeister@gmail.com
License: MIT/Apache-2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: cffi, asn1crypto
Home:Dev m$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import coincurve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named coincurve
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the python2 shell?. In some Linux distributions, you have to specify the python version as `python2` to enter its shell.

Comment: You were right. The correct answer is to start it with `python2`. Do you want to put it in as an answer and I'll mark it as correct? Thanks.

Comment: I have just done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually in the *python 2.7* shell. In some Linux distributions, you have to specify the python version to get into its shell. So you run the following command:

```
python2
```

Instead of:

```
python
```

Because the above command automatically opens the *python 3.x* shell.